# Strings and dates conditions

Tags: python

```
data = [{'A':"re", "B": 120630, "C": 120630, "D": "Sunday"}, {'A':"aeg", "B": 121228, "C": 130104, "D": "Monday"}, {'A':"aab", "B": 120601, "C": 120608, "D": "Sunday"}, {'A':"bbe", "B": 120925, "C": 120630, "D": "Monday"}, {'A':"feh", "B": 120726, "C": 120803, "D": "Monday"}, {'A':"dd", "B": 120622, "C": 120630, "D": "Monday"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["B"] = pd.to_datetime (df["B"], format="%y%m%d")
df["C"] = pd.to_datetime (df["C"], format="%y%m%d")
```

I want to select the rows with both conditions:

- *Column D* is "Monday".
- *Column B* date is 7 or 8 days before *Column C* date.

I mean, I want to get these rows:

```
aeg 2012-12-28 2013-01-04  Monday

feh 2012-07-26 2012-08-03  Monday

dd  2012-06-22 2012-06-30  Monday
```

I´ve tried:

```
df[(df["D"] == "Monday") & (df["B"] < df["C"])]
```

But this code doesn´t satisfy the second condition (*Column B* date is 7 or 8 days before *Column C* date).

Any other idea?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please also specify what you have already tried ? If you haven't tried anything yet, please do start and then ask a question when you are stuck. Please provide some code. Please also take a moment to read [how-to-ask on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way.

```
df.loc[(df["D"] == "Monday") & (df["B"] - df["C"]).dt.days.isin({-7, -8})]

#      A          B          C       D
# 1  aeg 2012-12-28 2013-01-04  Monday
# 4  feh 2012-07-26 2012-08-03  Monday
# 5   dd 2012-06-22 2012-06-30  Monday
```